# Find Git cherry pick parent

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have done a cherry-pick from branch PRIVATE to branch MASTER.
Done without -x (since done from GUI).
It created a commit with conflict. Resolved and committed.

I want to see in the future that this commit is a cherry-pick from branch PRIVATE to branch MASTER.

There is no trace of that!
When I do:

```
git log --cherry
```

I DO see this commit on MASTER, but I cannot find its parent (the private branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cherry pick a commit a Git, you are actually making a completely *new* commit.  Hence, the commit you made has nothing to do with the original commit and its branch.  If you want to explicitly mark this commit as being a cherry pick, then you may use the `--edit` option:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick --edit <SHA-1 of private commit>
```

This tells Git to pause and open the commit message editor before finishing the commit.  There, you may enter some text which marks the commit as a cherry pick.

Note that if you've already made your commit, but you haven't committed anything else to `master` just yet, you can still *amend* the cherry pick commit via `git commit --amend`.  Then, change the commit message to whatever you want to see.